# How to Sanitize the SQL in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-injection, sanitization, find-by-sql

I'm new to this RoR world,

I've many SELECT sql queries in my RoR Application, something like this

```
@replies  = Offerreply.find_by_sql ("SELECT * FROM offerreplies WHERE 
offer_id="+params [:offer_id])
```

Some are very simple like above and some are very complex JOINS. most of them are suffering from **SQL Injection**  problem. So., How to Sanitize such SQL statements in RoR?

Edit: How to Handle same in SQL statements which has JOINS and Sub-queries? something like this

```
@to_be_approved=Beneficiary.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM beneficiaries WHERE project_id="+params[:id]+" AND NOT id IN (SELECT beneficiaries.id FROM beneficiaries INNER JOIN beneficiaryloans ON beneficiaryloans.beneficiary_id=beneficiaries.id AND beneficiaryloans.hfi_id="+session[:id].to_s+" AND beneficiaries.status_id=4) AND cso_id IN(SELECT user_id FROM user_projects INNER JOIN users ON  user_projects.user_id=users.id AND users.user_type_id=2)")
```

Comment: Why are you using `find_by_sql`? If you use `find` or `where` you don't have to worry about SQL injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Rails 3 (as your tag says), you can do it like this.

```
@replies  = Offerreply.where("offer_id = ?", params[:offer_id])
```

You can find more information [at the Rails site](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions).

edit: If you have more than one condition, you can do it like this.

```
@replies  = Offerreply.where("offer_id = ? AND second = ?", params[:offer_id], params[:second])
```

edit2: And see Micha's answer for multiple joins.

Comment: @ShreekumarS - if you want to use Rails you *really* have to learn the [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). [Here's the paragraph on joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables). Only use `find_by_sql` if there is no way of doing it via the "normal" interface.

Answer (score 3):

Waynn Lue's answer is fine, but it doesn't show how to query on joined tables. You can do it like this:

```
Offerreply.joins(:offers).where('offers.id', params[:offer_id])
```

Or:

```
Offerreply.joins(:offers).where(:offers => { :id => params[:offer_id] })
```

Again: if you want to use Rails you really have to learn the [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). [Here's the paragraph on joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables). Only use find_by_sql if there is no way of doing it via the "normal" interface.

Comment: Thanks for writing this, edited a reference into my answer and upvoted. :)